# Will be a bug of SimpleDateFormat.parse 

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz2);
String aDate = "2012-05-02 23:59:59";

for(int i=0 ; i<1000; i++){
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        ParsePosition p = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(aDate, p);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
        if (p.getIndex() != aDate.length())
           throw new RuntimeException("just a test");

}
```

After testing plenty of times, it was very stranger. Basically, it never be finished completely, it ran into exception very randomly.

You see the code should be correct, but: it ran into exception when maybe `i` is 500 or `i` is 799 or `i` is 988(just take some examples here, means it was not getting happened when `i` = 0, it actually has finished some circles), the exception may get thrown in either line Date `date = dateFormat.parse(aDate, p);` or line `throw new RuntimeException("just a test");`;

Can everybody advice me whats wrong?

Comment: Please write the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"After testing plenty of times"*  That rubbish does not **compile** due to things like `if (p.getIndex() != aDate.length())
           throws RuntimeException("just a test");`

Comment: Let your code (fixed to compile) run for three minutes uninterrupted with no error.  Perhaps you could show us the real code that actually doesn't work?

Comment: sorry, this was typo, has fixed, real code can compile and work.

Comment: Bhavik Ambani: it happened more often with p.getIndex() != aDate.length(), the index of ParsePosition is 0 and errorindex is 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat.parse()` uses an instance variable called `calendar` to build the date from the string.  If two threads try to parse at the same time, the `calendar` variable will get clobbered and you'll get wrong results.

Making the variable not static won't necessarily help, since two threads could still be using the same controller.  A better solution is to either create a new DateFormat object each time you parse a date, or use thread local storage.  Better still, use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which has thread safe parsers.

Also consider the following points while using SDF.

1. Creating SimpleDateFormat is [expensive](http://www.thedwick.com/blog/2008/04/simpledateformat-performance-pig/). Don't use this unless it's done seldom.
2. OK if you can live with a bit of blocking. Use if formatDate() is not used much.
3. Fastest option IF you reuse threads ([thread pool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)). Uses more memory than 2. and has higher startup overhead.

For applications both 2. and 3. are viable options. Which is best for your case depends on your use case. Beware of premature optimization. Only do it if you believe this is an issue.

For libraries that would be used by 3rd party I'd use option 3.

Answer (score 2):

Your code just plain works, even after 20 reruns. So let's take a guess at what your **real** SSCCE might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  dateFormat.setLenient(false);
  final String aDate = "2012-05-02 23:59:59";
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    new Thread() { public void run() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        ParsePosition p = new ParsePosition(0);
        dateFormat.parse(aDate, p);
        if (p.getIndex() != aDate.length())
          throw new RuntimeException("just a test");
      }
      System.out.println("Done");
    }}.start();
}
```

This breaks, more or less the way you describe, and for obvious reasons. Listen to @Bhavik Ambani's advice, he's covering this for you.

Comment: OK, so now it just works. There are two warnings about unused vars, though.

Comment: what you mean "only number 2. applies."?

Comment: From my numbered list of two items, the point number two applies, whereas point number 1. doesn't (your code compiles).

Comment: He's saying, the code works.  It runs, no exceptions.  To help you we need to see the actual real code that throws exceptions, not a reduced example that works fine.

Comment: sorry, I was not mean the code works(no exception), it has exception occurred as described in content above, I meant the code was compiled and can run, the issue code in here is due to typo.

Answer (score 0):

p.getIndex() != aDate.length()

This statement is returning true, which means that when you parsed the date you did not consume the entirety of string aDate, mean aDate either has timezone or other information also

Comment: but you see here the aDate = "2012-05-02 23:59:59", is is a absolute right date string.